# SQLALchemy denormalizing field from relationship

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a model with a self-relationship and a denormalization field with some value from the related row. Is there any way to keep them in sync automatically, without having to channel the relationship through a property?

Example:

```
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_parent = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id))
    data = Column(String(64))
    last_modified = Column(DateTime, onupdate=utcnow)
    parent_last_modified = Column(DateTime, onupdate=utcnow)

    parent = relationship('Node', remote_side=[id])
```

I'd like to keep parent_last_modified in sync with parent.last_modified anytime it's changed. It's even better if I can get to parent_last_modified through parent.last_modified and reach the denormalized field instead of making a new query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following event callback solved the problem:

```
@event.listens_for(Node.parent, 'set')
def node_parent_listener(node, parent, previous, initiator):
    if parent is None:
        node.parent_last_modified = None
    else:
        node.parent_last_modified = parent.last_modified
```